# The player element passed isn’t a Vimeo embed. Player JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Vimeo player's JavaScript API for starting a video when a user clicks on the specific button on the site.

Here's the embedded code:

```
<iframe id="vimeo-player" src="<?php the_sub_field('slide_video'); ?>?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="1880" height="1058" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

Here's the JavaScript:

```
    var iframe = document.querySelector('#vimeo-player');
    var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

    $('.slide-area__slides__video svg').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).closest('.item').find('img').hide();
        $(this).siblings('iframe').show();
        player.play();
    });

    player.on('ended', function(data) {
        $('.slide-area__slides__video svg').show();
        $('.slide-area__slides__video iframe').hide();
        $('.slider-area__slides .item img').show();
    });
```

It works perfectly in Chrome, but in every other browser, it just keeps throwing the error:

> The player element passed isn’t a Vimeo embed.

Has anyone encountered this before? It's quite frustrating.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at player.js, it seems that the error displays when:

```
if (element.nodeName === 'IFRAME' && !isVimeoUrl(element.getAttribute('src') || '') {...}
```

Make sure the_sub_field('slide_video') outputs a valid Vimeo URL.

Comment: If anyone is hitting this, it's because you are using an iframe with no src. Change it to a div

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [NYCjbd](/u/3551617) in an earlier comment, my problem was related with lazy load. Turning it off for iframes solved it. Many thanks.